"Attempted relative import beyond top-level package" even fo the code from official docs
I have a (simple) case of needing to share utils modules with other packages in one level and below. But I cannot - when I do relative import with two dots to import from other package like
from ..utils import foo I get an error ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package. Finally, I decided to read the docs where it is told

In either subpackage1/moduleX.py or subpackage1/__init__.py, the following are valid relative imports

I made this simple project:
package1/
   __init__.py
   module_x.py
   module_y.py
package2/
   __init__.py
   module_z.py
__init__.py
module_a.py

where all __init__.py are empty except
# package1/__init__.py

from .module_y import spam
from .module_y import spam as ham
from . import module_y
from ..package1 import module_y
from ..package2.module_z import eggs
from ..module_a import foo

and
# module_a.py

import package1

def foo():
    pass

and other files implement empty functions with eggs, spam and ham.
And when I run module_a.py I got an error
C:\Anaconda\python.exe ...\py_import\module_a.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\py_import\module_a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import package1
  File "...\py_import\package1\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..package1 import module_y
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Ran from PyCharm and from Anaconda Prompt with python module_a.py from the project dir - the result is the same. Used python 3.10.13 from Anaconda on Windows.
Can anybody help to understand what is going wrong? I thought the case of sharing the funcs from the top-level package (like some utils located in a subsequent package) is the regular practice.
